# Unable to view map in released apk

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, maps

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure. Please see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how 
to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console 
(https://console.developers.google.com)</p>
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
```

I am getting the above error. The application works fine but i am unable to view the map in released version.

I have checked the following points:

- API key is correct
- I couldn't find Google Maps Android API v2 but I have enabled Google Maps Android API
- The debug apk works
- I have created sha1 for release build

Please help

Comment: Your api key might be correct, try to check for [proper configurtion in the google console.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information)

Comment: It finally worked. The thing that i missed was that there are 3 sha1 keys, debug, release and the one that google provides when you upload your apk. I had to insert the google verified sha1 in google maps api. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: Glad that worked! would you mind putting that an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked. The thing that i missed was that there are 3 sha1 keys, debug, release and the one that google provides when you upload your apk. I had to insert the google verified sha1 in google maps api.

Answer (score 0):

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/09/generate-sha1-fingerprint-of-release.html

User this link and generate sha1 key with your release keystore file and then add this SHA1 key to your google developer console where you set debug sha1 key.